# taxfield lock dynamically but tab key can reach and edit the text field .. How can i fixed it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

"Model.LupInventoryView" returns "1" if editable and "0" if non-editable .And it is working fine but when it is in non-editable mode tab key can reach the field and the user can make changes .. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrdQty, new {@class = Model.LupInventoryView[0].PrdQtyEditable == false ? "form-control disabletxt" : "form-control", @placeholder = "Current Quantity"})

Comment: Is 'taxfield' intended or do you mean tab field or text field? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry it is "text field"..